# Need regex pattern solution for the given problem

Tags: java, regex

I have below line of text

Name student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9
Kishan student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9

For above line I want to get the name of the student, passed or failed and comma separated subject and marks. 
Looking for a regex solution.

I have tried the below code to match the regex

```
String example = "Kishan student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=.student\\s).*").matcher(example);

Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("(.*?)student").matcher(example);
```

I am getting the out put 
first match "Pass,Maths=10,Science=9"
second match "Kishan student"

Further I am not getting idea to continue. Any lead will help me.

Comment: You might split on `student`

Comment: The name is everything up to the first space or up to the word "student", so it can be solved using ```firstIndexOf```. For the grades, you could parse them as CSV  by setting the line seperator to "," and the value seperator to "=" (i think opencsv can do this out of the box - or you can use ```replace```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this expression might be to some extent close to what you may have in mind,

```
(?i)(.*?)\s+student\s+([^,\r\n]*),([^=\r\n]*)=([0-9.]*),([^=\r\n]*)=([0-9.]*)
```

not sure though.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?i)(.*?)\\s+student\\s+([^,\\r\\n]*),([^=\\r\\n]*)=([0-9.]*),([^=\\r\\n]*)=([0-9.]*)";
        final String string = "Some Name student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9 Kishan student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9.1 Some Other Name Student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9 Kishan student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9.3";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: Some Name student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9
Group 1: Some Name
Group 2: Pass
Group 3: Maths
Group 4: 10
Group 5: Science
Group 6: 9
Full match:  Kishan student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9.1
Group 1:  Kishan
Group 2: Pass
Group 3: Maths
Group 4: 10
Group 5: Science
Group 6: 9.1
Full match:  Some Other Name Student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9
Group 1:  Some Other Name
Group 2: Pass
Group 3: Maths
Group 4: 10
Group 5: Science
Group 6: 9
Full match:  Kishan student Pass,Maths=10,Science=9.3
Group 1:  Kishan
Group 2: Pass
Group 3: Maths
Group 4: 10
Group 5: Science
Group 6: 9.3
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oQhfKg/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/oQhfKg/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]